# Render div from Mvc Model

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have model List with fields `ContainerId(div id), Code(html-code)`, which I pass to Razor View.

What is the best way to render code from model in containerId?

---

What I think is to use jquery : find element by `id` and use `.html()` function to set `code`. But I hardly can imagine how go throught list and render code for each id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="@Model.ContainerId">
    @Html.Raw(Model.Code)
</div>
```

Or actually, since you have a list:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div id="@item.ContainerId">
        @Html.Raw(item.Code)
    </div>
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply. What should i do if i have already some placeholders or existing `<div id="@item.ContainerId">` ? How can i found them is DOM?

Comment: What are you talking about? Unless you're using AJAX to fetch some new data, there's no "existing" anything. Nothing exists until it's been rendered by Razor and sent to the browser.

Comment: ok, i have view where i add few div's like `<div id="div1"></div>`. So when i pass model this containers exists?

Comment: Sorry, still not making sense. There's no need for "placeholders" like that. Just render the HTML you want the page to have. This is all happening in the same scope, so if you print static HTML like that to the page you're saying you want that output to the client. If that's not what you want, then remove that static HTML and use the code I gave you instead.

Comment: i mean that i want to render that divs in places which i setup before. If i will run your second sample, i will get list of divs one after another, wright? I want to place them in different places on page